# Nginx load balancer show incomplete HTTPS pages

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, reverse-proxy

I have to configure an NGINX server in order to load balance 2 ore more https websites.

I wrote this code:

```
 user  nginx;
#worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

#    sendfile        on;
#tcp_nopush     on;

#    keepalive_timeout  65;

        upstream servers_alpha {
                least_conn;
                #server 10.200.0.43:801 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
                server 10.200.0.43:443 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
                #server 10.200.0.70:801 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
                server 10.200.0.141:443 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
                              }


server {
                        #listen       80;
                        listen 443 ssl;
                        #ssl on;
                        ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl/proxy1/server.crt;
                        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/proxy1/server.key;
                        server_name  proxy1;

location / {
                proxy_pass      https://servers_alpha;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                }

location /nginx_status {
        stub_status on;
        access_log   off;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
#        allow 10.200.0.111;
        allow 10.5.1.101;
         deny all;
}
}
#location / {
#        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
#        index  index.html index.htm;
#    }
    }
```

The 2 servers I'm using in this example are:
**10.200.0.43** --> Spacewalk
**10.200.0.141** --> Ansible

If I browse those sites directly there are no issues, the sites are fine and browsable.
If I pass through NGINX the sites are incomplete and not working: useless, unusable, as you can see in the images:

[Ansible 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Re6xA.png)

[Ansible 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdrqL.png)

[Spacewalk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2HAx.png)

This is the access.log:

```
10.5.1.101 - - [04/Sep/2018:17:38:36 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 216 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0" "-"
10.5.1.101 - - [04/Sep/2018:17:38:36 +0200] "GET /rhn/Login.do HTTP/1.1" 404 3360 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0" "-"
10.5.1.101 - - [04/Sep/2018:17:38:36 +0200] "GET /static/rest_framework/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 5086 "https://10.200.0.69/rhn/Login.do" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0" "-"
10.5.1.101 - - [04/Sep/2018:17:38:36 +0200] "GET /static/api/api.css?v=3.0.2 HTTP/1.1" 200 7442 "https://10.200.0.69/rhn/Login.do" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0" "-"
10.5.1.101 - - [04/Sep/2018:17:38:36 +0200] "GET /static/rest_framework/css/default.css HTTP/1.1" 200 1132 "https://10.200.0.69/rhn/Login.do" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0" "-"
10.5.1.101 - - [04/Sep/2018:17:38:36 +0200] "GET /static/rest_framework/js/csrf.js HTTP/1.1" 200 1832 "https://10.200.0.69/rhn/Login.do" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0" "-"
10.5.1.101 - - [04/Sep/2018:17:38:36 +0200] "GET /static/rest_framework/css/prettify.css HTTP/1.1" 404 5086 "https://10.200.0.69/rhn/Login.do" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0" "-"
10.5.1.101 - - [04/Sep/2018:17:38:36 +0200] "GET /static/rest_framework/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 36816 "https://10.200.0.69/rhn/Login.do" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0" "-"
10.5.1.101 - - [04/Sep/2018:17:38:36 +0200] "GET /static/rest_framework/js/prettify-min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 13632 "https://10.200.0.69/rhn/Login.do" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0" "-"
10.5.1.101 - - [04/Sep/2018:17:38:36 +0200] "GET /static/rest_framework/js/default.js HTTP/1.1" 200 1760 "https://10.200.0.69/rhn/Login.do" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0" "-"
10.5.1.101 - - [04/Sep/2018:17:38:36 +0200] "GET /static/api/api.js?v=3.0.2 HTTP/1.1" 200 3145 "https://10.200.0.69/rhn/Login.do" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0" "-"
10.5.1.101 - - [04/Sep/2018:17:38:36 +0200] "GET /static/assets/main_menu_logo.png HTTP/1.1" 200 6359 "https://10.200.0.69/rhn/Login.do" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0" "-"
10.5.1.101 - - [04/Sep/2018:17:38:36 +0200] "GET /static/rest_framework/js/ajax-form.js HTTP/1.1" 404 5092 "https://10.200.0.69/rhn/Login.do" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0" "-"
10.5.1.101 - - [04/Sep/2018:17:38:36 +0200] "GET /static/rest_framework/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 95957 "https://10.200.0.69/rhn/Login.do" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0" "-"
10.5.1.101 - - [04/Sep/2018:17:38:36 +0200] "GET /static/rest_framework/js/ajax-form.js HTTP/1.1" 404 5092 "https://10.200.0.69/rhn/Login.do" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0" "-"
10.5.1.101 - - [04/Sep/2018:17:38:36 +0200] "GET /static/assets/favicon.ico?v=3.0.2 HTTP/1.1" 200 15086 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0" "-"
```

While the error.log:

```
2018/09/04 17:38:36 [warn] 17259#17259: *243 an upstream response is buffered to a temporary file /var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp/2/00/0000000002 while reading upstream, client: 10.5.1.101, server: proxy1, request: "GET /static/rest_framework/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://10.200.0.141:443/static/rest_framework/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js", host: "10.200.0.69", referrer: "https://10.200.0.69/rhn/Login.do"`
```

Can  you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

ps: If I redirect on http it works fine